# How to separate daily data (increasing, decreasing, growth) with a conditional index?

Tags: r

I have daily tree growth data, which I would like to separate into: increasing, decreasing and growth. While I worked out how to define increase and decrease, I cannot workout how to define growth.

Increase: Area increases between consecutive timestamps 
Decrease: Area decreases between consecutive timestamps 
Growth: Subset of increase, where current daily maximum area is bigger than prev. daily maximum area

Here's what the data looks like:

```
df = data.frame(
  "Date" = c(rep("31/07/2019", each= 4),rep("1/08/2019", each=                                             
             11),rep("2/08/2019", each= 14)) ,
  "DateTime" = c("31/07/2019 22:13","31/07/2019 22:33","31/07/2019 23:13",
                 "31/07/2019 23:43","1/08/2019 15:42","1/08/2019 15:45",
                 "1/08/2019 15:50","1/08/2019 15:55","1/08/2019 16:00",
                 "1/08/2019 16:05","1/08/2019 16:11","1/08/2019 16:37",
                 "1/08/2019 16:57","1/08/2019 17:02","1/08/2019 17:08",
                 "2/08/2019 0:53","2/08/2019 1:14","2/08/2019 3:14",
                 "2/08/2019 4:14","2/08/2019 9:06","2/08/2019 9:36",
                 "2/08/2019 10:36","2/08/2019 11:36","2/08/2019 15:39",
                 "2/08/2019 16:39","2/08/2019 17:39","2/08/2019 18:39",
                 "2/08/2019 19:39","2/08/2019 20:39"),
  "Area" = c(
    94236, 94276, 94416, 94456, 94434, 94287, 94285, 94215, 94104, 
    94007, 94007, 94047, 94087, 94127, 94167, 94247, 94287, 94327, 
    94367, 94497, 94467, 94437, 94407, 94487, 94521, 94607, 94667, 
    94727, 94787) )
```

This is how I defined increase and decrease:

```
d5 = df%>%
        mutate(Diff = Area - lag(Area))%>% 
        group_by(Date) %>% 
        mutate(class = ifelse (Diff >= 0,'increase', 'decrease' ) )%>%
         select(DateTime, Date, Area, class)
```

Now increase is both: increase and growth.
I would like to replace increase with growth everywhere, where the current day Area exceeds the max Area of ALL previous days.

For example: the maximum Area on 31 Jul is 94456. 
Now, every Area which is bigger than 94456 on the 1st Aug should be growth and not increase. 
If growth was detected, the threshold separating increase and growth should adjust. The new threshold should be the highest Area value of the 1st Aug (94434).

All following separations of growth and increase should NOT only take into account the previous day maximum Area (comparing max area on the 2. Aug to area on the 1st Aug) but all previous max areas (comparing max area on the 2. Aug to area on the 31 Jul and 1st Aug) and only detect growth if the area is bigger than all previous measured areas.

If no growth was detected, the threshold separating increase from growth should remain unchanged and move to assess the next day.

I tried using ifelse and an index.
The problem is, that I am not sure how to create a conditional index which checks the daily Area data and adjusts when exceeded.

This is what I would like to end up with:

```
d5 = data.frame(
  "Date" = c(rep("31/07/2019", each= 4),rep("1/08/2019", each=                                             
                                              11),rep("2/08/2019", each= 14)) ,
  "DateTime" = c("31/07/2019 22:13","31/07/2019 22:33","31/07/2019 23:13",
                 "31/07/2019 23:43","1/08/2019 15:42","1/08/2019 15:45",
                 "1/08/2019 15:50","1/08/2019 15:55","1/08/2019 16:00",
                 "1/08/2019 16:05","1/08/2019 16:11","1/08/2019 16:37",
                 "1/08/2019 16:57","1/08/2019 17:02","1/08/2019 17:08",
                 "2/08/2019 0:53","2/08/2019 1:14","2/08/2019 3:14",
                 "2/08/2019 4:14","2/08/2019 9:06","2/08/2019 9:36",
                 "2/08/2019 10:36","2/08/2019 11:36","2/08/2019 15:39",
                 "2/08/2019 16:39","2/08/2019 17:39","2/08/2019 18:39",
                 "2/08/2019 19:39","2/08/2019 20:39"),
  "Area" = c(
    94236, 94276, 94416, 94456, 94434, 94287, 94285, 94215, 94104, 
    94007, 94007, 94047, 94087, 94127, 94167, 94247, 94287, 94327, 
    94367, 94497, 94467, 94437, 94407, 94487, 94521, 94607, 94667, 
    94727, 94787) ,
  "class" = c("NA", rep("increase", each= 3), rep("decrease", each= 6),
                    rep("increase", each= 7), rep("growth", each= 3), 
                    rep("decrease", each= 3), rep("increase", each=  1), rep("growth", each= 5) )
  )
```

Comment: Please explain why the down-vote. The question may be lengthy, but it has data, code the user tried and expected result. This is more than I can say about 95% of questions, which is why I upvoted.

Comment: Area=94456 is for July 31st and not August 1st. Does this change anything?

Comment: Hi Roman, sorry about the datetime chaos. It was suppose to be the 1st of Aug.

Comment: Can you edit your question to reflect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a very convoluted way to do this and assuming I have understood you correctly

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(DateTime = as.POSIXct(DateTime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), 
         Date  = as.Date(DateTime)) %>%
  arrange(DateTime) %>%
  mutate(class = c("increase", "decrease")[(Area - lag(Area) < 0) + 1]) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(prev_max = max(Area)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(prev_max = lag(prev_max)) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(prev_max = first(prev_max), 
         class = case_when(class == "increase" & Area > prev_max ~ "growth", 
                       TRUE ~ class)) %>%
  select(-prev_max)


#   Date       DateTime             Area class   
#   <date>     <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>   
# 1 2019-07-31 2019-07-31 22:13:00 94236 NA      
# 2 2019-07-31 2019-07-31 22:33:00 94276 increase
# 3 2019-07-31 2019-07-31 23:13:00 94416 increase
# 4 2019-07-31 2019-07-31 23:43:00 94456 increase
# 5 2019-08-01 2019-08-01 15:42:00 94434 decrease
# 6 2019-08-01 2019-08-01 15:45:00 94287 decrease
# 7 2019-08-01 2019-08-01 15:50:00 94285 decrease
# 8 2019-08-01 2019-08-01 15:55:00 94215 decrease
# 9 2019-08-01 2019-08-01 16:00:00 94104 decrease
#10 2019-08-01 2019-08-01 16:05:00 94007 decrease
# … with 19 more rows
```

This first converts `DateTime` to `POSIXct` value and `Date` to Date. We then assign  `c("increase", "decrease")` value based on comparison with previous row value. For each `Date`, we compare it with previous `Date`s `max` value and change the `class` to `"growth"` if it is greater.

---

**EDIT**

For the updated question where we need to compare the `Area` with all the previous dates max

```
df1 <- df %>%
        mutate(DateTime = as.POSIXct(DateTime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), 
               Date  = as.Date(DateTime)) %>%
        arrange(DateTime) %>%
        mutate(class = c("increase", "decrease")[(Area - lag(Area) < 0) + 1]) %>%
        group_by(Date) %>%
        mutate(prev_max = max(Area)) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        mutate(prev_max = lag(prev_max)) %>%
        group_by(Date) %>%
        mutate(prev_max = first(prev_max)) %>%
        ungroup


df1 %>%
   mutate(prev_max = cummax(replace(prev_max, is.na(prev_max), 0)), 
          class = case_when(class == "increase" & Area > prev_max 
                            & prev_max != 0 ~ "growth", 
                            TRUE ~ class))
```

Comment: Kay. While I did not specify it, is it somehow possible to make the code so flexible, that it not only compares (to classify growth) to the last day's maximum value but to all previous maximum area values?

Comment: @CaroP so something like `df %>%
  mutate(DateTime = as.POSIXct(DateTime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), 
         Date  = as.Date(DateTime)) %>%
  arrange(DateTime) %>%
  mutate(class = c("increase", "decrease")[(Area - lag(Area) < 0) + 1], 
         class = case_when(class == "increase" & Area > cummax(Area) ~ "growth", 
                           TRUE ~ class))
  ` ?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying better what I mean. I updated the question now.  In short :I would like to define growth not only by comparing with the previous day maximum Area (comparing max area on the 2. Aug to area on the 1st Aug) but all previous max areas (comparing max area on the 2. Aug to area on the 31 Jul and 1st Aug) and only detect growth if the area on the 2 Aug is bigger than all previous measured areas ( 31Jul and 1 Aug).

Comment: @CaroP ok..I have updated the answer. Please look at the part after **EDIT**.